# How can I run router firmware in a virtual system?

Tags: emulation, virtualization, virtualbox, qemu

I am interested in doing customization's to a router firmware. I want to run the router firmware in a virtualized environment so that i can run the modified code instantly without having to burn it into the router itself. And also any bugs also can be discoverd easily. And finally most importantly i will not have any risk of having to throw away my router due to buggy code.  Is it possible to run router Operating systems on virtualbox and test it ?

Answer (score 3):

Most routers are based on MIPS processors. VirtualBox allows you "emulate" (it's not real emulation is the only virtualization) only your host processor (probably it's x86 or x86_64). So you can't use this software to do this. Try qemu software - it's a real emulator and can emulate lots of kinds of processors, including MIPS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/) and [Dynamibs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamips), that way you don't need Virtualbox and will be able to manage console to all virtual-routers through GNS3 nice GUI.